# How to add a new page that will function as a separate blog/news article page

Tags: posts, templates

My template does not have more than one blog post -So what I think I need to do is create a template to retrieve posts and apply it to the page. The problem is I think this will only work if the page has BOTH a template that has a loop calling post AND is set to not be a static page.

Here is the template code:

```
 <?php
/* 
Template Name: Archives-custom
*/
get_header(); ?>

<div id="primary" class="site-content">
<div id="content" role="main">

<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

<!--<div class="entry-content"> -->
<div class="ArchiveHalf">
<?php the_content(); ?>

/* Custom Archives Functions Go Below this line */

<div class="archivePost">
                                    <h2 class="archiveH2"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                                    <p style="margin-bottom: 16px;">
                                        <?php echo __('Posted by', 'ultimate-showcase') . ' <a href="' . get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ) . '">' . get_the_author() . '</a> ' . __('on', 'ultimate-showcase') . ' ' . get_post_time('F j, Y') . ' ' . __('in', 'ultimate-showcase') . ' ' . get_the_category_list( ', ' ); ?>
                                    </p>
                                    <div class="clear"></div>
                                    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ){ ?>
                                        <div class="thumbnailImage"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></div>
                                    <?php } ?>
                                    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                                </div> <!-- archivePost -->

/* Custom Archives Functions Go Above this line */

</div><!-- .entry-content -->

<?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

</div><!-- #content -->
</div><!-- #primary -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I'm not seeing any results on the page. What am I missing? The trouble is it looks like I can set only one page to be a blog at a time. When I go to the "reading" settings it only allows me to set the home pge to static and designate ather to be a blog page -I need a second blog page to display another category or archive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through doing some poking around, the short answer is NO. There cannot be two actual blog pages on a site. For my purposes I wanted a "Blog page" which needed to be customized to show only one category and I wanted to make a very customized template (multi columns for instance), and STILL have a another page which will display another category or an archive.

The SOLUTION: Use a pluggin with shortcode to output a category or categories to a different static page. It can be customized by using some css columns. One might also do [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0x4OwuraoJY) -but I don't want the page displayed in a menu.

The limitations though are that making a display template that is very customized for a second display is harder.